# canvas problem unity canvas and button don't want to move at the same time

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, canvas, move

I want the text to move independently of the canvas

the text moves with the canvas. And I don't want that. How do I fix it.

i use unity

There aren't many details about it. When the camera moves, the canvas moves with it. the buttons move with the canvas. I don't want the button to move with the canvas.

Comment: children move along with their parents. Check that the button is not a canvas children so that it does not move with it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button as a UI element in Unity, you have to create a button object that will be placed under a canvas or the canvas's children. You'll have a canvas in the hierarchy of a button, and if you found the button has to be independent of the canvas, you have to create a new canvas since the first canvas is not its parent and make the button as its child.

[image: First canvas and the button]

[image: 2 canvases and the button]